# Pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence for Lipschitz functions?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of Lipschitz functions $f_j:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with uniform Lipschitz constant $L\in(0,\infty)$.  Suppose there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (not necessarily Lipschitz or even continuous) for which $f_j\to f$ pointwise, i.e. $\lim_{j\to\infty}f_j(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  Does it follow that $f_j\to f$ uniformly, i.e. that $\lim_{j\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|f_j(x)-f(x)|=0$?

I know this is true for Lipschitz sequences on compact metric spaces, and that it is not true for arbitrary metric spaces.  However, I seem to recall hearing that it was true for $\mathbb{R}$, which would make it true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ too, I believe.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not true on $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb R^n$): For example, take $f_n(x)=x$ for $|x|\le n$ and $f_n=\pm n$ otherwise.

Comment: Okay cool, thank you!